# May I add a second subview to window if rootViewController is a UISplitViewController to simulate a modal effect?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm currently using `UISplitViewController` as my app's rootViewController. To present progress dialogs I use `presentModalViewController`, but for the one and other reason I'm not entirely happy with it and want to do my own modal thing.

If one of my modal views is supposed to be shown, I want to add another subview to my app's main window. This subview is going to be managed by its own `UIViewController` subclass to make it rotate properly and do all the stuff I need.

Is this design aproach okay or will I run into issues with `UISplitViewController` (it is very special in so many ways and seems to be offended easily if not treaten right! :-))?
Is it a problem to have two `UIViewControllers` next to each other?

Please don't discuss "why don't you use presentModalViewController then?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be ok with `UISplitViewController` if you do it properly, as `presentModalViewController` does something similar.

One alternative you should look into is `UIPopoverController` and the UIViewController's `modalIfPopover` property.

Also, you say you aren't happy with `presentModalViewController` and perhaps if you say what was wrong with it we can help you work around whatever issues you have with it.  This is the exact case that it seems to be meant for.

Comment: It is hard to get the modally shown view transparent, it can be resized after being displayed only, it causes problems if you have to present a 2nd modal controller on top. Still, I use it all over the place but I have faced too many restrictions in one particular case, that's why I look for an alternative.

Comment: Popovers get over some of those restrictions.  Resizing them can be tricky but is doable.  Under what circumstance do you end up with a stack of modals?  There may be a different workflow that can avoid that as well.